# How to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x \to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{16x^6-x^2}}{6x^3+x^2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

How I approach this problem:-

$\displaystyle \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{16x^6 - x^2}}{6x^3+x^2}$
$= \displaystyle \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6(16 - \frac{x^2}{x^6}})}{x^2(6x+1)}$

$= \displaystyle \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{x^3\sqrt{16 - \frac{1}{x^4}}}{x^2(6x+1)}$
$= \displaystyle \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{x\sqrt{16 - \frac{1}{x^4}}}{6x+1}$

$= \displaystyle \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{16 - \frac{1}{x^4}}}{6+\frac{1}{x}}$

Now the answer to this problem is $-\frac{2}{3}$ but it doesn't seems to match with the last expression. What I observe in the initial step is the numerator is positive because of the even powers and denominator is negative because cubic power dominates square power and we get negative in the denominator. Still what if we didn't knew the initial step and knew only the last one. How one will conclude it's $-\frac{2}{3}$. Whether $x \to -\infty \;\text{or}\; \infty$ the last expression always comes out to be $\frac{\sqrt{16}}{6}$ or my steps are wrong?

Comment: $\sqrt{x^6}=-x^3$ when $x<0$.  (Saying $\sqrt{x^6}=x^3$ is a common mistake.)

Comment: *Hint*: What is $\sqrt{16}$

Comment: @wjmccann As I remember $\sqrt{16}$ will be $4$ not $-4$

Comment: It could be simpler to let $x=-\frac 1 y$ and work around $y=0$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  why not $\frac{1}{y}$, just asking. I forgot, I need revision

Comment: Just to get rid of the minus and related problems. Just try both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made a typical mistake. It is **not true** that
$$
\sqrt{a^2} = a
$$
for **any real number $a$**; it is true that
$$
\sqrt{a^2} = |a|
$$
for **any real number $a$** instead.

---

$$
\lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^6(16 - \frac{x^2}{x^6}})}{x^2(6x+1)}
= \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\color{red}{|x^3|} \sqrt{16 - \frac{1}{x^4}}}{x^2(6x+1)}
= \lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\color{red}{-x^3} \sqrt{16 - \frac{1}{x^4}}}{x^2(6x+1)}
$$
because $x < 0$ as $x \to -\infty$.

---

Never forget the symbol of absolute value.

Comment: It's been two months since I did all this and I think I need revision. I knew about it but forgot. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, in these cases, to avoid confusion we can set $x=-y \to \infty$ then

$$\lim_{x  \to -\infty} \frac{\sqrt{16x^6 - x^2}}{6x^3+x^2}=\lim_{y  \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{16y^6 - y^2}}{\color{red}{-6y^3}+y^2}=-\frac23$$